# Making an Observable from a callback

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, rxjs

I have an auth guard that needs an asynchronous response true/false when the site is visited and the user is already logged in.

I'm using Firebase's `onAuthStateChanged` ([link to docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#getRedirectResult)) and it uses a callback function.  How can I turn my `isLoggedIn()` method into something that can return `Observable<boolean>`?

Typscript:

```
get isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {

    // want something like this:
    return Observable.fromCallback(firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged).map(user => !!user);

    // this returns () => boolean, but I need a promise or observable
    return firebase
      .auth()
      .onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        return !!user;
      });

}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
get isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {

  // want something like this:
  return Observable.create(
    observer => firebase
        .auth()
        .onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          observer.next(!!user)
        });
    );
}
```

Comment: Beware that this will add a listener with each property access/subscription and that said listener will not be removed. The arrow function passed to `create` should return the result of the `onAuthStateChanged` (which is a function that removes the listener). Doing so will see the listener removed when the observable is unsubscribed.

Comment: @cartant or rohit would you mind add an example of subscribing / unsubscribing to make this answer a bit more thorough?

Comment: `onAuthStateChanged()` returns the unsubscribe function so you just need to remove the curly braces in the subscription function when you create the Observable: `Observable.create(observer => firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => observer.next(!!user)))`.

Comment: [bindCallback](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindNodeCallback) is the modern approach for the problem since RxJs 6. Checkout [these examples](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindCallback#convert-jquery-s-getjson-to-an-observable-api).

Answer (score 15):

there is one more way of doing this using bindCallback from rxjs/observable/bindCallback

```
const observable=bindCallback(functionWhichExpectsCallBack)
```

e.g

```
function foo(value, callback) {
  callback(value);
}
//converts callback to observable
    const observable = bindCallback(foo); 
    observable(1)
      .subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 8):

Note: `bindCallback` and `Observable.create` were deprecated,
you could use `new Observable` instead:

```
...
return new Observable((subscriber) => {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      subscriber.next(user);
    })
}
```

Comment: `bindCallback` is not deprecated https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindCallback