# Using a Callback Function in AuthGuard

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

if I have the following implementation of CanActivate in an AuthGuard:

```ts
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if (token) {
    this.authService.userInfo(token, (err, result) => {
        if (err) return false;
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Will the guard wait until the callback function executes, knowing that `userInfo` below actually uses HTTP to call Auth0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the return signature of [`CanActivate`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html)'s `canActivate` method is:

```
Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean
```

so it *can* deal with an asynchronous response.

However, that's **not** what you're giving it; if there is a `token` you return a boolean, but if there isn't you return nothing at all; the `return` *inside the callback* doesn't alter what's returned from `canActivate` at all. So, as currently written, the guard will not wait for the response from the service.

If you control the service you should refactor it to use observables rather than taking a callback, as that fits much more naturally into the RxJS-based Angular world. If not, you will need to convert the callback to a promise or observable; see e.g. [Making an Observable from a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43131162/3001761), or [`fromCallback`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromcallback.md). For consistency, you should also `return Observable.of(false)` in the other case.

Comment: Sorry, there's an `else` missing up there, since I was just writing the code for demonstration purposes... but I guess that would not change your answer?

Comment: @Sammy well without the `else` it will always return false, but still: no waiting, unless you return something it can wait fort.

Comment: Alright so what you're saying is if I return an observable of a boolean it will simply wait for it to emit something first. That's ok! But then again, may you tell me why on several other threads I've been reading that I should use the `.first()` operator? I don't get that!

Comment: You mean `Observable.first`? That just means you only return the *next* value emitted by the observable, then it completes, so if other values appear in the future they aren't included. I'd recommend some time looking into reactive streams/RxJS; once you get the hang of it things feel much more natural. I wrote a blog article on some of the stuff my team is doing with it: http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html